# Como hacer entidades en springboots a partir de una bbdd ya desarrollada?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, spring-boot

Quiero realizar entidades de una base de datos de producción,  donde necesito algunas tablas para trabajar . La base de datos tiene información y quiero poder hacer consultas vía Jparepository

Comment: Hola Lucas, bienvenido, tu pregunta se parece mucho a "tengo este ejercicio, resuélvanlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.